# What git command lines can i use to remove all my local directory on my computer?

Tags: git, github

so I created empty git local directories on my computer under different files. What command line can I use to clear all of them and start over? And also a follow up question, why can't I see my current local git directories?

Comment: `rm -r` can be used to delete a directory. Or you could also use `mv` to move the git / working directories (if they were just placed inappropriately but otherwise OK). These are not a git commands. See `man rm`, eg, for details. On windows the `rmdir` and `move` commands can be used.. or point'n'click :} Also, there is no difference (except for that it contains git meta data) between a git working copy and a 'normal' directory. If such a directory cannot be seen then it does not exist or you are looking in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

Using your terminal, navigate to the folder that contains the git repository.

```
$ cd <path/to/folder>
```

Then verify the existence of a `.git` folder using `ls -la`. Those folders are hidden (note the "dot" before the name).

Remove the `.git` folder using:

```
$ rm -rf .git
```

This will remove the git repository from your project folder, allowing you to start over fresh.

Go to your remote repository account (i.e. Github) and create an **EMPTY** new repository.

Than copy the repository URL which will look something like this:

```
https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY>.git
```

Initialize a new git repository in your project folder (if you want):

```
$ git init
```

Than add all your project files to version control:

```
$ git add .
```

Commit all your files, to get them ready to send to your remote repository:

```
$ git commit -m 'First commit to remote repo'
```

Add your remote origin to your local git:

```
$ git remote add origin <REPO_URL>
```

Verify your origin branches

```
$ git remote -v
```

Finally, push your first commit to your remote repository

```
$ git push origin master
```